# Plotting bargraph using groupby from dataframe columns

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to matplotlib & python. Need to plot the following sample data in bar graph in python from dataframe columns:

```
Company    Year        PnL_Percent

Company A   02          5
Company A   04          7
Company A   06          3

Company B   02          2
Company B   04          8
Company B   06          3

Company C   02         10
Company C   04         14
Company C   06         06
```

The actual code gets data from almost 50+ companies and Years in steps of 2 yr range from 2 yrs to 12 yrs. So there will be 06 bars for each company on x-axis and profit/loss percent on y-axis.Though I tried but not able to get the exact bar graph..though the data looks simple to plot.

Please help to get a pythonic way of plotting the bar graph..as the actual data is voluminous.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You may want to read through the help center, especially [ask] and [mcve]. Most importantly show what you have tried, i.e. have you searched for "pandas grouped bar chart" or similar? In how far does that not solve your problem? Show this via code.